# Combo Box will not display data

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I am working on a small program to copy files to a clipboard. The ComboBoxes are filled based on folders/files in specified directory. The first `comboBox` filled appropriately. Now that the second comboBox has been added the first box no longer displays, and the box that is showing has no items loaded in.

Updated: I've rewritten the code and can now see the second comboBox. The data that is stored in Object [] subFiles is not being passed into second comboBox

```
public class s2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener, Runnable{

    public static File folder = new File("u:/response");
    static String temp = "";

    final JComboBox t1 = new JComboBox();
    final JComboBox t2 = new JComboBox();
    final Object [] files;
    Object [] subFiles;

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<File> list2 = new ArrayList<File>();

    public s2() {     

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<File> list2 = new ArrayList<File>();

    for (File fl : folder.listFiles())
    {
        list1.add(fl.getName().toUpperCase());
    }

    files = list1.toArray();
    t1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(files));

    }


    public class tier1 implements ActionListener
    {   
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int i = t1.getSelectedIndex();

            File node = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile() + "\\" + list1.get(i));
            listFiles(node);

            subFiles = list2.toArray();
            t2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(subFiles));
    }    

    }

    public class tier2 implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e2){    

            }
        }

    public static void listFiles (File folder){
          for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()){
             if (fileEntry.isFile()){
                 temp = fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();
                 list2.add(fileEntry);
                 System.out.println(temp);

             }
          }
      }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Response Library");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        UtilityBar ub = new UtilityBar();
        f.setJMenuBar(ub.menuBar);

        f.add(this);
        f.add(t1);
        f.add(t2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (75,300));   

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new s2());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame` uses `BorderLayout` as the default layout manager. When you do

```
f.add(t1);
f.add(t2);
```

both the combo boxes are placed in the same position (`BorderLayout.CENTER`), and the layout manager supports only one component at each position.

```
f.add(t1);
f.add(t2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Would place the second below the first, so then both the combo boxes should be visible.

Also, you should create and access swing components only in the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Thank you @kiheru. You suggestions helped me to get the second box comboBox visible. I rewrote the code to what I think you meant in your comment referring to the event thread.